# How to nest when/otherwise statements?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to test some values with a nested if statement but it doesn't seem to work. The first when block works fine but when it hits the otherwise and goes into the when test=$country, it breaks. The text "Outside when and country is ..." works fine. The problem is that the last two paragraphs do not get printed out. I'm not sure if it's something to do with the way I am nesting the when statements as I am new to XSLT.

Country is when I change the locale of the website to US OR GB.

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="target = 'FX'"> <!-- Normal page -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$country = 'US'">
            <p>Inside FX US. Country is <xsl:value-of select="$country" /></p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <p>Inside FX GB. Country is <xsl:value-of select="$country" /></p>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise> <!-- Graph page -->

<p>Outside when and country is <xsl:value-of select="$country" /></p>
    <xsl:when test="$country = 'US'">
        <p>Inside LPBM US. Country is <xsl:value-of select="$country" /></p>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <p>Inside LPBM GB. Country is <xsl:value-of select="$country" /></p>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Please add the input XML and the desired output HTML. Nesting `<xsl:chosse>` is very likely not your best option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last block does not have a open and close `<xsl:choose>` block around it. Try adding those in and see if you get the desired results.

Your XSLT should look like the following:

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="target = 'FX'"> <!-- Normal page -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$country = 'US'">
            <p>Inside FX US. Country is <xsl:value-of select="$country" /></p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <p>Inside FX GB. Country is <xsl:value-of select="$country" /></p>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise> <!-- Graph page -->

<p>Outside when and country is <xsl:value-of select="$country" /></p>
    <xsl:choose> <!-- Added this line -->
        <xsl:when test="$country = 'US'">
            <p>Inside LPBM US. Country is <xsl:value-of select="$country" /></p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <p>Inside LPBM GB. Country is <xsl:value-of select="$country" /></p>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose> <!-- Added this line -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Also, I'm sure there is a better way to do this but I don't have time right now to write that up. I might come back to this to recommend a better approach in a while.